# Change the URL root path in ASP.NET MVC or IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, url-rewriting, iis-8.5

I'm working with a server with a custom URL: http://example.com/site/ and as you can see I need to change the default root path ("/") of my application to prevent 404 errors. Using IIS rewrite module with a outbound rule seems to work, with all html links and references being converted properly to query the internal website. The problem is when a `Redirect()` or `RedirectToAction()` method is used in my controllers, the internal name of the website is dropped so a 404 is caused. This is my IIS outbound rule:

```
<rewrite>
  <outboundRules>
    <rule name="Add path prefix to urls" stopProcessing="true">
      <match filterByTags="A, Form, Img, Link, Script" pattern="^/(.*)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" value="/site{R:0}" />
    </rule>
  </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

So to clarify: I have http://example.com/site/ when a redirection occurs to Account/Login, it becomes http://example.com/account/login instead of http://example.com/site/account/login . I guess the RouteConfig has to be tinkered with but I don't know how, or if I can do this in IIS. I have the following in my RouteConfig class:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "SiteRoot",
    url: "site/{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

Thank you.

Comment: why not just create a virtualdirectory called site under you website directory(www.example.com) and copy the code to there. It would work the way you wanted.?

Comment: @pjobs I can't, the server root is example.com/site/, If I create a virtual directory then I would have example.com/site/site/

Comment: Have you got the answer yet? I also has the same issue when deploy my mvc react app onto IIS server, IIS will assign a virtual path for the application.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the issue is only with pages protected by the authorize annotation, you probably need to update the `/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs` file to change the login path. You're looking for `LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),` which you'll change to `LoginPath = new PathString("/site/Account/Login"),`. In the MVC 5 starter site I tested in this was on line #28.

In my testing with your redirect rule and route configuration normal `RedirectToAction`s worked fine, but if you're having trouble you might try removing the "Default" route mapping so that URL structure isn't selected by the router when trying to redirect.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need the `/site/` root path for all the URLs, including images, scripts and static files in general. I can't use the ASP.NET routing in this files. `RedirectToAction` doesn't work with IIS outbound rules :(